# All my test passes and Cypress doesn't show all the steps and keep spining loading alike

Tags: cypress

I am doing e2e with Cypress
and all my test case pass but on the browser there are no steps, as this pictures shows, and also the circle remains spinning with no end:

[image: All test cases passes but the circle remains spinning]

I try with several test and all is ok

Where should I look? Any advice on how I can fix this?

With any suggestion I will update the post

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code of the test so we can help on what might be wrong ?

Comment: of course, let me update the initial request